# Why would LIMIT 2 queries work but LIMIT 1 always times out?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan, postgresql-performance

I'm using this public Postgres DB of NEAR protocol: https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer#shared-public-access

`postgres://public_readonly:nearprotocol@mainnet.db.explorer.indexer.near.dev/mainnet_explorer`

```sql
SELECT "public"."receipts"."receipt_id",
    "public"."receipts"."included_in_block_hash",
    "public"."receipts"."included_in_chunk_hash",
    "public"."receipts"."index_in_chunk",
    "public"."receipts"."included_in_block_timestamp",
    "public"."receipts"."predecessor_account_id",
    "public"."receipts"."receiver_account_id",
    "public"."receipts"."receipt_kind",
    "public"."receipts"."originated_from_transaction_hash"
FROM "public"."receipts"
WHERE ("public"."receipts"."receipt_id") IN
        (SELECT "t0"."receipt_id"
            FROM "public"."receipts" AS "t0"
            INNER JOIN "public"."action_receipts" AS "j0" ON ("j0"."receipt_id") = ("t0"."receipt_id")
            WHERE ("j0"."signer_account_id" = 'ryancwalsh.near'
                                        AND "t0"."receipt_id" IS NOT NULL))
ORDER BY "public"."receipts"."included_in_block_timestamp" DESC
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 0
```

always results in:

```
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
SQL state: 57014
```

But if I change it to LIMIT 2, the query runs in less than 1 second.

How would that ever be the case? Does that mean the database isn't set up well? Or am I doing something wrong?

P.S. The query here was generated via Prisma. `findFirst` always times out, so I think I might need to change it to `findMany` as a workaround.

Comment: Using EXPLAIN on both queries yields wildly different plans.   The plan for the LIMIT 1 is actually quite a bit better, and uses index scans.   It should return quite a bit faster, not slower.   Do you have access to the error logs?

Comment: @KirkRoybal Thanks for your ideas. I don't think I can get access to the logs, but we'll see.

Comment: @kirkroybal where did you find the plans?

Comment: @jjanes: the db is publicly accessible, login details in the github link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query can be simplified /optimized:

```sql
SELECT r.receipt_id
     , r.included_in_block_hash
     , r.included_in_chunk_hash
     , r.index_in_chunk
     , r.included_in_block_timestamp
     , r.predecessor_account_id
     , r.receiver_account_id
     , r.receipt_kind
     , r.originated_from_transaction_hash
FROM   public.receipts r
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM public.action_receipts j
   WHERE  j.receipt_id = r.receipt_id
   AND    j.signer_account_id = 'ryancwalsh.near'
   )
ORDER  BY r.included_in_block_timestamp DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

However, that only scratches the surface of your underlying problem.

Like Kirk already commented, Postgres chooses a different query plan for `LIMIT 1`, obviously ignorant of the fact that there are **only 90 rows** in table `action_receipts` with `signer_account_id = 'ryancwalsh.near'`, while both involved tables have more than **220 million rows**, obviously growing steadily.

Changing to `LIMIT 2` makes a different query plan seem more favorable, hence the observed difference in performance. (So the query planner has the general idea that the filter is very selective, just not close enough for the corner case of `LIMIT 1`.)

You should have mentioned **cardinalities** to set us on the right track.

*Knowing* that our filter is so selective, we can force a more favorable query plan with a different query:

```sql
WITH j AS (
   SELECT receipt_id  -- is PK!
   FROM   public.action_receipts
   WHERE  signer_account_id = 'ryancwalsh.near'
   )
SELECT r.receipt_id
     , r.included_in_block_hash
     , r.included_in_chunk_hash
     , r.index_in_chunk
     , r.included_in_block_timestamp
     , r.predecessor_account_id
     , r.receiver_account_id
     , r.receipt_kind
     , r.originated_from_transaction_hash
FROM   j
JOIN   public.receipts r USING (receipt_id)
ORDER  BY r.included_in_block_timestamp DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

This uses the same query plan for `LIMIT 1`, and either finishes in under 2 ms in my test:

```
                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=134904.89..134904.89 rows=1 width=223) (actual time=1.750..1.754 rows=1 loops=1)
   CTE j
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on action_receipts  (cost=319.46..41564.59 rows=10696 width=44) (actual time=0.058..0.179 rows=90 loops=1)
           Recheck Cond: (signer_account_id = 'ryancwalsh.near'::text)
           Heap Blocks: exact=73
           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on action_receipt_signer_account_id_idx  (cost=0.00..316.79 rows=10696 width=0) (actual time=0.043..0.043 rows=90 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: (signer_account_id = 'ryancwalsh.near'::text)
   ->  Sort  (cost=93340.30..93367.04 rows=10696 width=223) (actual time=1.749..1.750 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: r.included_in_block_timestamp DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.70..93286.82 rows=10696 width=223) (actual time=0.089..1.705 rows=90 loops=1)
               ->  CTE Scan on j  (cost=0.00..213.92 rows=10696 width=32) (actual time=0.060..0.221 rows=90 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using receipts_pkey on receipts r  (cost=0.70..8.70 rows=1 width=223) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=90)
                     Index Cond: (receipt_id = j.receipt_id)
 Planning Time: 0.281 ms
 Execution Time: 1.801 ms
```

The point is to execute the hugely selective query in the CTE first. Then Postgres does not attempt to walk the index on `(included_in_block_timestamp)` under the wrong assumption that it would find a matching row soon enough. (It does not.)

The DB at hand runs **Postgres 11**, where CTEs are always optimization barriers. In **Postgres 12** or later add [`AS MATERIALIZED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH) to the CTE to guarantee the same effect.
Or you could use the **"OFFSET 0 hack"** in any version like this:

```sql
SELECT r.receipt_id
     , r.included_in_block_hash
     , r.included_in_chunk_hash
     , r.index_in_chunk
     , r.included_in_block_timestamp
     , r.predecessor_account_id
     , r.receiver_account_id
     , r.receipt_kind
     , r.originated_from_transaction_hash
FROM  (
   SELECT receipt_id  -- is PK!
   FROM   public.action_receipts
   WHERE  signer_account_id = 'ryancwalsh.near'
   OFFSET 0  -- !
   ) j
JOIN   public.receipts r USING (receipt_id)
ORDER  BY r.included_in_block_timestamp DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Prevents "inlining" of the subquery to the same effect. Finishes in < 2ms.

See:

- [How to prevent PostgreSQL from rewriting OUTER JOIN queries?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/131436/3684)

#### "Fix" the database?

The proper fix depends on the complete picture. The underlying problem is that Postgres overestimates the number of qualifying rows in table `action_receipts`. The MCV list (**m**ost **c**ommon **v**alues) cannot keep up with 220 million rows (and growing). It's most probably not just `ANALYZE` lagging behind. (Though it could be: `autovacuum` not properly configured? Rookie mistake?) Depending on the actual cardinalities (data distribution) in `action_receipts.signer_account_id` and access patterns you could do various things to "fix" it. Two options:

##### 1. Increase `n_distinct` and `STATISTICS`

If most values in `action_receipts.signer_account_id` are equally rare (high cardinality), consider setting a very large `n_distinct` value for the column. And combine that with a moderately increased `STATISTICS` target for the same column to counter errors in the other direction (*under*estimating the number of qualifying rows for common values). Read both answers here:

- [Postgres sometimes uses inferior index for WHERE a IN (...) ORDER BY b LIMIT N](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/249617/3684)

And:

- [Very bad query plan in PostgreSQL 9.6](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/287375/3684)

##### 2. Local fix with [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html)

**If** `action_receipts.signer_account_id = 'ryancwalsh.near'` is special in that it's queried more regularly than others, consider a small partial index for it, to fix just that case. Like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON action_receipts (receipt_id)
WHERE signer_account_id = 'ryancwalsh.near';
```

Comment: THANK YOU for this thorough answer! There is a lot for me to learn here, so I will go back through it many times. Was / is it fair of me to expect that a LIMIT 1 query would never be significantly slower (especially to the point of timing out) than the LIMIT 2 version of that query (which runs very quickly) even *if* (as you've shown) there were ways I could have written my query to be more efficient? I imagined that I'd have discovered a "problem" with the way that NEAR created this DB. But I can't tell whether you're suggesting that they fix anything (or need to upgrade to Postgres 12). Tks!

Comment: @Ryan: I added possible tweaks for the db itself.

Comment: @Ryan: As for `fair of me to expect that a LIMIT 1 query would never be significantly slower`: Yes, as long as the same query plan is used. No, in the case at hand.